# MVC Web Application will not load aspx web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created three aspx web pages in the views>home directory of my project, with paths ~/Home/Enter, ~/Home/List, and ~/Home/Search. I can see that the paths are correct in my properties window in visual studio, as well as the solution explorer. However, whenever I click on the link to these pages on the site, I get an error message stating that "
The view at '~/Views/Home/Enter.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl."

I have uploaded a screenshot of the error below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

HomeController.CS Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GolfScores.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Search()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Enter()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult List()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Add view menu:
[image]

Comment: Show your controller methods. Do you have a `Search()` method in `HomeController`?

Comment: Just added it to the original code. I added one in, but the error still exists

Comment: Your `@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Home")` will work fine. But the 'Enter' link wont because it needs to be `"Enter"`, not `"Enter.aspx"`)

Comment: Changing Enter.aspx to enter made it so the mvc application could find the pages, but now I am getting a new error. I am updating the original post to reflect this

Comment: How are you generating those views? The fact that you have files `Enter.aspx.cs` and `Enter.aspx.designer.cs` suggests something weird. To create you view, right click in the method, click 'Add View' and select 'ASPX' as the view engine. It will generate the correct view code with `<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>` (but why are you mixing `aspx` and cshtml` views anyway?)

Comment: I was attempting to mix the views because I am more familiar with how to create one using asp than html. I do not have the option to add a aspx view engine in Visual Studio 2013, is there a way to add it in?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - when you add a new view, the dialog will have a dropdown to select either 'Razor' or 'ASPX'

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio 2013? In my version I don't have a dialogbox that lets me pick between the two, it just defaults to razor with no option. I can include a screenshot in the original post to show what I am looking at.

Comment: Yes, Just tested it in 2013.

Comment: Just added a screenshot of what my "Add View" looks like

Comment: Which version of MVC? What you should be seeing is as per [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-view) unless your using MVC-5 (in which case its not supported)

Comment: I'm using MVC 5.2.3. Do you know about any workarounds for this? I tried downgrading it to 3.0 but then nothing worked in the entire application

Comment: The use of ASPX was dropped in MVC-5 (and its no longer supported so I suggest you learn the much easier/cleaner razor syntax). But you can always just add a file with a `.aspx` extension to the view folder and then add `<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>` to the top and go from there.

Comment: So are my current aspx files usable at all? Or do I need to go somewhere else to create a completely new aspx file to add this to?

Comment: My best guess is that you have just copies those files fro a web forms app? In which case, I doubt that they are going to work at all and you will need to create new files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your Search Page class to inherit `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` class, instead of `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Your Search.aspx.cs should look like:

```
public partial class Search : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about MVC, not web forms (there is no such thing as events (`Page_Load(..)`) in MVC)

Comment: True, any callback wont work as it will hit the controller. However, changing the class to inherit from ViewPage will load the aspx.